# Edit All SharePoint Forms View

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, forms-services, edit-form

Is that possible to edit all SharePoint Forms (View, Edit, New) to get something like this:

[Label and Input as a row](http://www.javascriptbank.com/javascript/article/50_Beautiful_Resources_of_HTML_Form_using_CSS_and_JavaScript/form-highlightning-examples-web-form-tutorial.jpg)

If it is possible, how can i do that ? Do i need to change the layouts/viewstyles.xsl or global/viewstyles.xml.

I don't know why, but every change that i do in these files it does not change the final view. It seems like SharePoint is using other template or layout, and i am changing the wrong file.

Answer (score 1):

Infopath Designer 2010 create a form which the one used through all (View, Edit, New) web pages.

Upon installing Infopath and navigating to your component (list, library, etc.), click violet "Customize Form" button on ribbon either in browser or in Sharepoint Designer 2010 to open, create and enable the form in Infopath Designer 2010, see on th right:

[image]

or create a form in Infopath Designer 2010 and publish your form.

Update (answering the comment):
In Infopath Designer 2010 the one and the same form created for a list.
That is, this Infopath form of type/compatibility "Sharepoint List Form" is unmodiafiable,

[image]

created automatically under the hood and its publishing from Infopath Designer 2010 creates, enables 3 web pages for Edit/Update, View/Display and New/Insert actions in Sharepoint on a list item:

- **displayifs.aspx**
- **editifs.aspx**
- **newifs.aspx**

instead of default Sharepoint form web pages

- **DispForm.aspx**
- **EditForm.aspx**
- **NewForm.aspx**

And the same form will be used in Infopath Web Part for this list inserted into any web page.

You can navigate to them in Sharepoint Designer 2010 All Files > Lists > choosing particlular list >

[image]

and the content of Items subdirectory:

[image]

You can edit them separately and even configure the use of 3 from both Infopath and non-IP web pages for  a list item but next publishing of IP form will override manual settings and only all 3 first web pages be used.

Once again, this is another side of codeless development, the developer does not have much control over it. The **Main Data Connection**, type of form (in case of "**Sharepoint List Form**" or **Workflow** types) are created automatically and closed for manual modification, editing, updating, choosing or even for viewing the internals

Comment: But to do that, i will need to edit each form for each List. I would like something more global.

Comment: There is only one and the same Infopath form of type/compatibility :Sharepoint List Form"  per a list for all Edit/View/New mode webpages  as well as for all web pages using Infopath Form Web Part of this list.